# Grabbing pieces inside .*? regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a log like below:

> EVENT: "[INIT]WinEvtLog: Security: AUDIT_SUCCESS(528): Security: Administrator: AMAZON-D071A6F8: AMAZON-D071A6F8: Successful Logon: User Name: Administrator Domain: AMAZON-D071A6F8 Logon ID: (0x0,0x1054A66) Logon Type: 10 Logon Process: User32 Authentication Package: Negotiate Workstation Name: AMAZON-D071A6F8 Logon GUID: - Caller User Name: AMAZON-D071A6F8$ Caller Domain: WORKGROUP Caller Logon ID: (0x0,0x3E7) Caller Process ID: 968 Transited Services: - Source Network Address: 10.0.0.200 Source Port: 60054 [END]";

I capture the log with this regex:

```
EVENT:\s\"\[INIT\](?P<log>.*?)\[END\]\";
```

I do this because I want to display the whole `EVENT` later.

There are pieces inside the `(?P<log>)` I also want to grab. For instance,

```
Source\sPort:\s(?P<src_port>\d+)
Source\sNetwork\sAddress:\s(?P<src_network_addr>\S+)
```

and among other things within `EVENT`.

I am not sure how I can create a regex to be able to grab the whole `EVENT` and also bits inside the `EVENT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

capturing groups inside another capturing group,

```
EVENT:\s\"\[INIT\](?P<log>.*?Source\sNetwork\sAddress:\s(?P<src_network_addr>\S+).*?Source\sPort:\s(?P<src_port>\d+).*?)\[END\]\"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vY0rD6/9)

The above regex would capture the `log`, as well as the `src_port` and `src_network_addr` which was present inside the `log`.

Comment: That only works if the elements are ordered and non-optional.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression listed below will match any event log that begins `EVENT: "[INIT]` and ends `[END]";`. If either of the phrases of interest are in the event log, they will be recorded.

Note the use of nested capture groups: `(?P<log>...(?P<src_port>...)...)`. The exterior group will capture its entire pattern, including anything captured by the interior group.

Also note that any group that does not participate in a match is still present in the resulting `dict`, with a value of `None`.

```
import re
from pprint import pprint


texts=[
    'EVENT: "[INIT]WinEvtLog: Security: AUDIT_SUCCESS(528): Security: Administrator: AMAZON-D071A6F8: AMAZON-D071A6F8: Successful Logon: User Name: Administrator Domain: AMAZON-D071A6F8 Logon ID: (0x0,0x1054A66) Logon Type: 10 Logon Process: User32 Authentication Package: Negotiate Workstation Name: AMAZON-D071A6F8 Logon GUID: - Caller User Name: AMAZON-D071A6F8$ Caller Domain: WORKGROUP Caller Logon ID: (0x0,0x3E7) Caller Process ID: 968 Transited Services: - Source Network Address: 10.0.0.200 Source Port: 60054 [END]";',
    'EVENT: "[INIT]Random text with one match Source Port: 60054 And stuff at end [END]";',
    'EVENT: "[INIT]Random text with no matches [END]";']


for text in texts:
  match = re.match(
    r'''
      (?x)                                 # Verbose
      EVENT:\s"\[INIT]                     # anchor from beginning
      (?P<log>                             # record entire entry
        (?:                                # consisting of:
          (?:Source\sNetwork\sAddress:\s   #  src_network_address
            (?P<src_network_address>\S+))
          |                                # OR
          (?:Source\sPort:\s               #  src_port
            (?P<src_port>\S+))
          |                                # OR
          .*?                              #  anything else
        )*                                 # as many times as required
      )
      \s\[END]";$                          # anchor at end
    ''',
    text)
  if(match):
    pprint (match.groupdict())
```

Result:

```
{'log': 'WinEvtLog: Security: AUDIT_SUCCESS(528): Security: Administrator: AMAZON-D071A6F8: AMAZON-D071A6F8: Successful Logon: User Name: Administrator Domain: AMAZON-D071A6F8 Logon ID: (0x0,0x1054A66) Logon Type: 10 Logon Process: User32 Authentication Package: Negotiate Workstation Name: AMAZON-D071A6F8 Logon GUID: - Caller User Name: AMAZON-D071A6F8$ Caller Domain: WORKGROUP Caller Logon ID: (0x0,0x3E7) Caller Process ID: 968 Transited Services: - Source Network Address: 10.0.0.200 Source Port: 60054',
 'src_network_address': '10.0.0.200',
 'src_port': '60054'}
{'log': 'Random text with one match Source Port: 60054 And stuff at end',
 'src_network_address': None,
 'src_port': '60054'}
{'log': 'Random text with no matches',
 'src_network_address': None,
 'src_port': None}
```